# Why do we dress up to celebrate Halloween?

Tags: traditions, rituals, calendar-dates, halloween

Why do people wear elaborate masks and costumes to celebrate Halloween?

Did people dress up during the pagan festivals that inspired Halloween, or is the practice a modern addition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Wikipedia page for [Halloween Costumes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_costume) it says:

> An early reference to wearing costumes at Halloween comes from Scotland in 1585.

Looking at the [external links on the page](http://www.loc.gov/folklife/halloween.html) I found something that sort of explains this.

> As the centuries wore on, people began dressing like these dreadful creatures, performing antics in exchange for food and drink. This practice is called mumming, from which the practice of trick-or-treating evolved.

This seems to be why we do it. In Samhain (the Celtic pagan ritual from which a large portion of Halloween tradition is derived), people would dress up. So yes, the tradition does come from the pagan holidays that it is based on.